# Rounded up value is received when using setMaximumFractionDigits

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and stuck at an issue. below is the sample program i made for the same.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object fieldVal = null;
        // Create the DecimalFormat Instance
        DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        String valStr = "31363.214722222422";

        deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(15);
        
        try {
            fieldVal = new BigDecimal(deciFormat.parse(valStr).toString());
        }
        catch (java.text.ParseException e){
            
        }
        System.out.println(fieldVal);
    }
}
```

Here I'm expecting the output as `31363.214722222422` but instead I'm getting `31363.214722222423`.
I observed that this rounding up happens for 12th decimal place. If I use till 11 decimal place, it works absolutely fine.
I even tried to avoid rounding up with `deciFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);`, but it didn't work.

Need some guidance to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use DecimalFormat because it will use `double` internally.  Instead parse it directly using `new BigDecimal(String)`

Comment: Or call [setParseBigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal(boolean))(true)

Comment: Thank you @Arhcimedes, as you have mentioned to avoid using of DecimalFormat as it is using double internally. does that mean it rounds up to nearest value?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's implementation dependent and I don't think it is speced out.